# i want to fetch linkedin company posts with node-linkedin

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

hello i want to fetch a linkedin company posts with

`node-linkedin`

and I have problems doing it and I cant find a working solution for this on internet.

Should I use other lib?

Comment: You don't _have_ to show us the code you've written so far. But it would help. https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide a lot of information so it's difficult to provide a truly helpful answer, but based on what you've written, I'd say it's likely you should use another library. [node-linkedin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-linkedin) has not had a version published in 6 years as of this writing and has at least one deprecated dependency. It might be fine, but it is very likely to have dependencies that have security vulnerabilities, contain bugs itself, etc.

LinkedIn provides a Node.js module called [linkedin-api-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linkedin-api-client). It's latest version was published relatively recently (3 months ago as of this writing). On the downside, it is (as of this writing) in beta, so it may be buggy. But it might be worth trying, depending on your requirements.